# iOS image resolution sizes with Sketch 3

Tags: ios, iphone, assets, sketch-3

I'm trying to understand the different image asset resolutions in Xcode/iOS development and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I use sketch 3 to develop the images I use in my apps.

So let's say I have an art board set up at the iPhone 5 size.  I've used this art board to create my images at the sizes I want them to be when displayed on an iPhone 5.  Would I export these images as 1x or 2x?

I've read that the iPhone 5 and 6 use the @2x resolution but this is where I start getting confused.  If I've created the images at the iPhone 5 dimensions would I really want to up the pixel count?

Any clarification would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Artboards are in 1x resolution.

When you export you should be doing it at 2x. For iPhone 6, 5, 4.

You should really be exporting all your assets at all 3 sizes since iOS 9 still supports the older 1x on iPad 2 (should your app also support iPad)

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed to know.